# Process.Start() Not Working in IIS published project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to open a URL of my application in browser using Process.Start() in my published project in IIS. But it is not opening the browser. Is there any other help in doing this?

Comment: Yeah, that's never going to work. IIS is not meant to create any UI apps. Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: any other help?

Comment: Um, I guess so. How about: Don't do this, it's madness.

Comment: you can't open a desktop application within a browser, this makes no sense at all. What's your actual end goal here? Perhaps there's another way to achieve your overall requirement.

Comment: i am trying to load webpage in background to create pdf.

Answer (score 0):

I think all you really need (if you want to launch a specific URL in a new browser window from a web application) is to call [`window.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) from javascript in your web application's HTML.

```
<button type="button" onclick="window.open('http://stackoverflow.com')">Open Browser</button>
```

Comment: I want to open browser using my published project. that's why i'm using Process.Start(). but it is not working.